# Oracle Linux 6.10 - Changing the Oracle user's ID & GID

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, oracle-12c, linux

> OS: Oracle Linux 6.10
>
> DB vers: 12cR1

I will backup and restore from NFS shared disk for a preprod server. However, the ID and GID of the oracle user on the production server (shared disk on producution) are different from the preprod server. For this reason, I need to change the ID and GID information, otherwise I cannot see the backup files on the preprod server. However, when I do this, there will be a problem on the datafile, oracle home and other existing ownerships on the preprod server. How can I perform this operation with the least amount of problems? It's fine as long as the downtime isn't taking too long on the preprod server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "For this reason, I need to change the ID and GID information,
> otherwise I cannot see the backup files on the preprod server."

No, you do not. You just need the necessary privilege to be able to read the backup files.

`chmod o+r backup_files`